# How do I combine two or more images to get a single pdf file?

Tags: pdf, graphics, macos

Say I have some image files (for instance, the result of scanning some sheets) and I want to combine them into a single pdf file, each image on a different page.
Is there a faster / more convenient way than converting each one to a pdf file and then combining those (say, as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-can-i-combine-two-pdfs-in-preview))? Or, if this is more or less how it is to be done, which is the most intelligent and less tedious possible way to do it?

Comment: The method in the link is the way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The link is about combining pdf files, and that is fine. What if I want to combine image files, and get a pdf as my result? Have I to convert them all into pdf files beforehand?

Comment: PDF's are known to have selectable and copyable text. Your images inside PDF won't have any of that.

Comment: @HMage: Yes, right. Indeed, my sheets have no text on them, so this is not much of an issue. But your remark is useful for people with a different problem.

Comment: To do this from the Photos application, select all the photos, click File => Print, click Print again, and then click Save as a PDF in the screen where you select your printer.

Comment: ref to https://superuser.com/a/854606/475424 too :)

Comment: If you need to do this on a large scale (more then 10 files), look at these 2 excellent answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/973/22003 https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312547/22003

Answer (score 308, accepted):

Here are the steps to save multiple images in Preview into a single multi-page PDF.

1. Select all of the images you want in your PDF, right-click and choose open with Preview
2. In Preview's Sidebar drag the images into the order you want them to appear in your PDF
3. Select/highlight all the images to be included in the PDF document; otherwise only a *single* image may end up the PDF document
4. Then from the "File" menu choose "Export Selected Images" (or "Export as PDF..." in recent OS X versions) and then "PDF > Save as PDF"

Comment: To avoid the margin which this method produces, use the Automator method in @SpaceMonkey13's answer (eg select one of: `Make all pages the same size`, `Size each page to fit`, or `Make all pages this size…`).

Answer (score 44):

Use `imagemagick`.

- Install `brew` (https://brew.sh/)
- `brew install imagemagick`
- `convert file1 file2 file3 output.pdf`

`files 1 through n` can be any image or pdf file.

Comment: If you are doing this once, then Preview is definitely the way to go.   
If you have to combine things on a recurring basis as part of your workflow, then the ability to do it with a cli or in a script is that much more useful.   
YMMV. Cheers.

Comment: This is the way to do it if you're at all comfortable with terminal. Great solution :)

Comment: The pdf print from preview made a gigantic file too big to email. I'd forgotten how wonderful imagemagick is.

Comment: I like this one much more. When you `print` there are margins, not good.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you have all your images in a single folder, you can do e.g. `convert *.jpg output.pdf` to include them all.

Comment: so much easier than having to click around in preview....

Answer (score 14):

This can be done using [Automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac). Follow these steps:

- Create a new Workflow.
- Under Actions, Library, Files & Folders add the **Get Specified Finder Items** as a step.
- On the bottom of that step click on **Add** and select the images.
- Next, under Actions, Library, PDFs add the **New PDF from Images**. The workflow should look like the one on the image:

[image: PDF from images automator workflow]

- Configure the step to your desire specifying among other things the location and name for the PDF file.
- Run the new workflow.
- In the **Results** tab of the New PDF from Images you now have your newly created PDF.

Comment: Thanks! This produced a file of equivalent size and quality to the `Preview > Print > PDF > Save as PDF`, but allowed me avoid the margin around my scans, using the options: `Make all pages the same size`, `Size each page to fit`, and `Make all pages this size:`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. Automator is a really cool feature! 

Answer (score 6):

Open Preview, make sure the Drawer is open and Drag the Image in underneath the Page Thumbnail.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried too. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but if I start with *image* files, I drop them one after another in the drawer, I select all and save as a pdf file, only one file ends up being saved in the pdf file I get. (Plus "what's so difficult in this method" is slightly patronising and not terribly helpful, if I may afford an opinion.)

Comment: Here's the Vimeo link :) http://vimeo.com/21771864

Comment: This adds terrible margins

Answer (score 3):

I made 2 quick screenshots for you:

1) select thumbnails view:

[image]

2) Drag second PDF e.g., from Desktop, into thumbnails pane, but above the thin silver line where the red arrow is pointing at (otherwise it won't be saved). And then just save the PDF

[image]

Comment: Please fix the images!

Answer (score 0):

If you use ImageMagick, the JPEG gets re-encoded, which results in [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), as well as worse performance.

Use `img2pdf` instead. Install using `pip3 install img2pdf`.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74341/374913

Answer (score -1):

When you try to print, sometimes you get the pages displayed rotated at 90 degrees, which is annoying. You could rotate all of them with one click from the PDF viewer but you will have to do that every time you open the file.

Instead, follow the top answer and when print to PDF, just uncheck Auto Rotate (preferred) OR select the horizontal orientation (hack). See the screenshot :) [image]

Answer (score -6):

paste in word and save as pdf...best possible way

Comment: I really hope this is sarcasm. I actually can't tell.