# How can I convert 100 photos into a pdf thats less than 6 MB?

Tags: macos

I need to convert 100 photos into a pdf file thats less than 6 mb. I use iPhoto to store my photos in. HELP!

Comment: simple math 6 mb / 100 = 60 kb each! so you have to shrink your photos to 60 kb each using any program such as Preview for example. Be aware that the quality will suffer, but if you size them down that will help.

Comment: Do you have Adobe Acrobat Pro?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) (free, open source, cross-platform, CLI) with the [`jpeg:extent=value` parameter](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) to compress each image to a target size, e.g. `mogrify -define jpeg:extent=60KB *.jpeg`

> Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example `-define jpeg:extent=400KB`. The JPEG encoder will search for the highest compression quality level that results in an output file that does not exceed the value. The `-quality` option is ignored if it is also present.

Then see [How can I convert JPG into PDF easily?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12709/20338)