# Using Imagemagick to convert TIFF to PDF

Tags: terminal, pdf, homebrew, file-conversion

[How can I convert JPG into PDF easily?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12709/how-can-i-convert-jpg-into-pdf-easily?newreg=0b40073d13354637adbafd109610191f) shows how to use `homebrew` to install `imagemagick` and then convert .jpg files into .pdf. I would like to convert many TIFF files to PDF, keeping the same name and changing only the extension.

For JPEG files, the advice was to use the following command:

1. `brew install imagemagick`
2. `convert *.jpg output.pdf`

I am trying to use the Step 2 command for *.TIFF files into *.PDF.

However, despite using the command line to the letter, I am unable to change my 300 files with this single line. In fact, no file is converted at all.

Would anyone be so kind to provide a helping hand ?

Comment: Have you tried the command `convert *.tiff output.pdf`? What message or output is returned?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i was looking to have each individual .jpg file to be converted into a .pdf file of the same name.

Comment: i tried this command but files are compl=iled into a single file. i'm looking to have individual files with the same name as the original file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` in `convert *.jpg output.pdf` expands to the list of inputs. This means the command you were actually running looked like:

```
convert one.jpg two.jpg three.jpg output.pdf
```

As you can see from this, that's not what you want, since all the images will be compiled into the output PDF. Also, as the command contains ‘jpg’, it looks for ‘jpg’ files, not ‘tiff’, so you need to change this too.

Therefore, you need to run that command for each of the inputs.

```
find /path/to/folder -iname "*.tiff" -exec convert {} {}.pdf \;
```

Comment: Thanks, and +1. However: Is that conversion lossless? That is, does the `convert` command just wrap the existing TIF or JPG files into a PDF file without altering the images, or does it first decompress the images and compress them again when embedding them into the PDF file?