# Can I efficiently make a pdf out of 10 jpeg images?

Tags: pdf, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I combine two or more images to get a single pdf file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11163/how-do-i-combine-two-or-more-images-to-get-a-single-pdf-file)

In Lion, how can I efficiently combine 10 jpeg files into a single pdf in which each image is a page? I have preview.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11163/14994

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to watch this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0ZyHLSMr7g) - it shows the scenario that I believe you're looking to solve - it uses Preview to create a multi-page PDF.

The steps are:

1. Open your images in Preview
2. Select `Print` from the `File` menu (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Click on the "`PDF`" button in the Print dialog and select "`Save as PDF...`" from the dropdown
4. Provide a file name and `Save`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Acrobat, you can simply select create Pdf from the file menu, then merge files into single pdf, it then gives you the option of small, medium or large size options